# Pandas Dataframe Filter Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to filter a dataframe to only include values that are equal to a certain value, or greater than another value.

Example dataframe:

```
              0            1             2  
0             0            1             23        
1             0            2             43
2             1            3             54     
3             2            3             77
```

From here, I want to pull all values from column 0, where column 2 is either equal to 23, or greater than 50 (so it should return 0, 1 and 2). Here is the code I have so far:

```
df = df[(df[2]=23) & (df[2]>50)]
```

This returns nothing. However, when I split these apart and run them individually (`df = df[df[2]=23]` and `df = df[df[2]>50]`), then I do get results back. Does anyone have any insights onto how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

As you said , it's `or` : `|`  not `and`: `&`

```
df = df[(df[2]=23) | (df[2]>50)]
```